# Error in Angular - has no exported member 'NgModule', 'BrowserModule', 'RouterModule'

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying a simple angular project with Django. I have a working Django project. I am getting this error during compiling.

> [0] app/app.module.ts(1,10): error TS2305: Module '"/user/blah-blah/angular/node_modules/@angular/core/index"' has no exported member 'NgModule'.
>   [0] app/app.module.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"/user/blah-blah/angular/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/index"' has no exported member 'BrowserModule'.
>   [0] app/app.module.ts(3,10): error TS2305: Module '"/user/blah-blah/angular/node_modules/@angular/router/index"' has no exported member 'RouterModule'.

app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { DepartmentListComponent } from './department-list.component';
import { EmployeeListComponent } from './employee-list.component';

@NgModule({
imports:      [ 
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
        {path: 'departments', component: DepartmentListComponent},
        {path: 'employees', component: EmployeeListComponent}
    ])
     ],
declarations: [ AppComponent, DepartmentListComponent, EmployeeListComponent ], 
bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have been following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2GsVcGo9diM&list=PLC3y8-rFHvwg5gEu2KF4sbGvpUqMRSBSW&index=31) for angular and [this](https://4sw.in/blog/2016/django-angular2-tutorial/) to use Django with Angular. According to one of the suggestions here in stack overflow, all rc4 has to be changed to rc5 in package.json but mine are all rc5 already. Where could I be possibly going wrong ?

Comment: Dumb question, but did you do an `npm install` ? It seems the compiler can't find the modules.

Comment: I did `npm install`

Comment: Okay, instead of giving you an answer, I can give you a workaround : why don't you make a new project using `ng init`, and put all your source code in it ?

Comment: `ng init` is removed. Edit (March 13, 2017): ng-init was removed from the latest version of the angular cli. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/pull/4628

Comment: Then use `ng new`, see [the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli)

Comment: Yes yes. I was just informing. I do consider your suggestion.

Comment: For angular-cli I had to update to 6.9.x or higher. Cli now is built around webpack rather than System.js which means there is no more `systemjs.config.js`. But any tutorial I see makes changes in `systemjs.config.js` file for integrating with `Django` which is my ultimate aim. Suggestions about any better tutorial to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145091/discussion-between-phanny-and-trichetriche).